# For a system of PDEs, how many equations are needed generally for the system to have unique solution?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

For an algebraic system of equations or a system of ordinary differential equations the following rule holds:(right?)

*the total number of unknown variables must be equal to the number of equations* (and also the same number of boundary conditions are needed, but that's not my question)

Is it generally correct for a system of PDEs too?

I asked [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/97812/is-the-system-of-equations-of-electrostatics-underdetermined-or-overdetermined) specific question on physics.SE, where one of the users presented the following example in comments saing that it is not the case for a system of PDEs :
$$\partial_x f=0 \,\,\,\,\,\partial_y f=0  \,\,\,\,\text{(two equations)}$$
$$\to f(x,y)=0 \,\,\,\text{(unique solution)}$$
(I've seen [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450367) question (without answer), which asks about number of needed boundary conditions; my question is about the number of independent equations needed)

Comment: With _spatial_ problems, the discretization of a PDE often results in a system of equations. Then the fact that _the total number of unknown variables must be equal to the number of equations_ can be employed the other way around: to establish what the proper Boundary Conditions must be for the original PDE. (I think it's sort of illegal to think of that, but I've done it.) With the discretization of a _time-like_ PDE
you have be certain (numerical/analytical) that the previous step completely determines the next one, which makes Initial Conditions PDE's an entirely different sort of problem.

Answer (score 2):

First, it is not true for algebraic systems that you need the same number of unknowns and equations to have a unique solutions. $$(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2,\ x^2 + y^2 =0 \Rightarrow x=y=0.$$

Second, it is not obvious how to characterize the dimension of the solution space of a PDE system. See chapter 8 of Seiler's book, "Involution: The Formal Theory of Differential Equations and its Applications".